# Construction of reals

Tags: real-analysis

Wanted to know whether I am correct in my understanding of real numbers.  The set of real numbers are DEFINED by a set of axioms whose elements we call the real numbers and the only problem is that we don't know whether a structure satisfying those axioms exist or not. So these structures can be constructed by dedekind cuts,cauchy sequences,etc.
So these constructions are mere construction but do not define what the set of real numbers are?
Thank you.

EDIT

Is the dedekind cuts a valid enough definition for reals? Suppose I take this as the definition, how can any other structure qualify as reals ? Also why does   spivak and rudin prove that all the ordered field axioms holds good for dedekind cuts(isn't basically using the axioms to show if the structure qualifies as real) if it is NOT just a mere construction?

Comment: You can INTRODUCE real numbers using axioms, that is, you assume that exists a set of elements (real numbers) that satisfies some certain properties. On the other hand, you can CONSTRUCT real numbers, understood as Dedekind cuts or Cauchy sequences of rational numbers.

Comment: So how do we DEFINE reals?

Comment: Food for thought for OP: ask the same questions about the set of natural numbers. You have the same "problems" defining the set of natural numbers as you do the set of real numbers, don't you? And these "problems" consist of: tentatively accepting the axioms and then going through the proof that the real numbers exist on the basis that the axioms are true and that you have accepted that the mathematical arguments proving the existence of the real numbers are valid and sound. I should mention that there are a lot of axioms needed to define the real numbers- Maybe OP doesn't know all of them?

Comment: As with many mathematical objects, there are several common ways of defining the real numbers, and one can then prove that the various definitions are equivalent (after which you can use whichever one is convenient).

Comment: It's not clear what you are hoping for here.  An axiomatic description is one thing, proofs of existence and uniqueness (in whatever sense that can be demonstrated) are different.  I'd say all are part of the definition.

Comment: @AdamRubinson For naturals we defined it as a set which follows Peanos axioms and existence of such a set is again an axiom in set theory.

Comment: My main doubt is that are dedekind cuts just a mere construction ?

Comment: What is "mere" about a construction?

Comment: To just  show a structure satisfying the axioms exist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is that it basically depends how far down the rabbit hole you want to go. You can define the real numbers as a complete ordered field, which actually defines them uniquely up to isomorphism, but in a sense you could argue this definition is a little artificial. We have done nothing to justify why in the world of Mathematics a complete ordered field should exist in the first place, so you may want to go deeper.

This is where the Dedekind cut and Cauchy constructions come in: we start with a much simpler set of axioms and then show these more simple axioms imply the existence of a complete ordered field. It feels "less artificial". I'm sure you could still debate the axioms that these constructions start with too, which really shouldn't be surprising (I mean, not even all Mathematicians agree with the concept of infinity).